# Looping input files with the file class

Tags: java, loops, input, output

I am trying to figure out how to loop a filename. I have 10 files
each file is called Myfile01.txt , Myfile02.txt, Myfile03.txt all the way to Myfile10.txt

I did something like this for the first file name , it is in java.

```
        String bob = new String("C:\\bob\\Myfile01.txt");

        File file = new File(bob);

        Scanner myinput = new Scanner(file);
```

Each file contains around 200 lines of data which i am storing in an array and using .hasnext to target what data goes into what array. each name is seperated with a line.

```
for (int i=0;i<=200;i++)
    {
        rank[i] = input.next();
        firstname[i] =input.next();
        lastname[i] = input.next();
        dadname[i] = input.next();
        momname[i] = input.next();
    }
```

now when i finish storing everything in the text file I am looking for a way to go to the next txt document with a loop to avoid clunkiness. I can hardcode it but it would not be good style.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

A loop and `String.format` should give you what you need:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    String bob = String.format("C:\\bob\\Myfile%02d.txt", Integer.valueOf(i));
    // ...
}
```

The format pattern `%02d` pads an integer with a zero given that it is less than two digits in length, as defined in the [syntax for string formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: so if i had MYfile2001.txt and myfile2002.txt that would not work?

Comment: It could work if you added `20` before the `%` in the string. If you want to be more flexible, though, you would need to adjust the initial value of the variable and the condition (and possibly the format pattern) to match the format of the file names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to walk through subdirectories you may also try:

```
try {
    Files.walk(Paths.get(directory)).filter(f -> Pattern.matches("myFile\\d{2}\\.txt", f.toFile().getName())).forEach(f -> {
        System.out.println("WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WITH f");
    });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```